# i want to make my nav smaller when the page loads and remove the logo from the nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(document).scrollTop() < '116px'){
                 $('#logo_top').hide();
            } else {
                $('#logo_top').show();
            }
        });
```

the code above is my jquery for trying to show and hide the image also 
the #navi-top must shift up when the image disipares

this is my html for my fixed navigation:

```
    <div id="navi" class="overflow">
        <div class="push-off-left-m">
            <div id="search-top" >

                <input id="search-box" onfocus="removeValue()" type="text" placeholder="EQUINITI GROUP" value="">
                <button id="btn-search"><img src="img/arrows.png" alt="arrows"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="navi-top" class="push-off-right-s">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">The Group</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="active">Working Together</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Paymaster</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Claybrook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Vote for a sidekick</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="logo_top" class="push-off-left-m" ><img src="img/logo.png" alt="EQUINITI GROUP"></div>


    </div>
```

Comment: "i want to make my nav smaller when the page loads and remove the logo from the nav" .. what's stopping you?

Comment: the code does not seem to work what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing a string '116px' with a number in javascript using lessThan always returns false, thus you never hide your logo.
[ScollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) returns an integer, simple compare it with *116*

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() < 116){
         $('#logo_top').hide();
    } else {
        $('#logo_top').show();
    }
});
```